# Rails and Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts

I'm trying to implement this style chart into my rails project.

```
<%= line_chart @goals.map{|goal|
{:name => goal.name, :data => goal.feats.group_by_week(:created_at).count }
} %>
```

I'm currently using Chartkick to do so. http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/
Here is how my tables are set up.

I want to track current_user Timesheets from 3 columns on my Timesheets table.

```
  def change
    create_table :timesheets do |t|
      t.decimal :teacher
      t.decimal :study
      t.decimal :conversation
      t.date :day
      t.references :user

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :timesheets, :user_id
  end
```

That is currently what my Timesheet Table looks like. How can I go about tracking :teacher, :study, :conversation through a chart through chartkick? I've read through the documentation, and can't quite grasp it. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do:

```
<%= line_chart [
  {name: "Teacher", data: current_user.timesheets.map{|t| [t.day, t.teacher] }},
  {name: "Study", data: current_user.timesheets.map{|t| [t.day, t.study] }},
  {name: "Conversation", data: current_user.timesheets.map{|t| [t.day, t.conversation] }}
] %>
```

Comment: When I enter this code I get an error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting '}' Any clue why?

Comment: @TonyTambe that's a ruby syntax error. Try to initialize array outside of hash and then insert it as a value of the data key and that error should go away.